# Can an arbitrary random vector be approximated by a normal random vector?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional **gaussian** random vector, and $Y$ be an $n$-dimensional random vector such that $\det(cov(X))\neq 0$ and  $\det (cov(Y))\neq 0$.

Then, does there exists a sequence of invertible $C^1$ functions $f_k$ such that $f_k\circ X \Rightarrow Y$ (weak convergence)?

Is there any reference related to this kind of problem?